# How can I personalize HTML emails using Mail Merge and Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, mail-merge

I'm attempting to personalize an email that uses HTML coding. Basically, I've made an HTML template that I want to have say the name of a person within the HTML code as well as the subject line of the email. For example: Subject line would be "Welcome to the club [name of contact]" and within the HTML body text have [name of contact] show up again. I'm using a Google Spreadsheet that has been scripted to run mail merge. Everything runs through the document. I've put all of the contacts on the spreadsheet with the script. Is this possible to personalize this?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926001/templated-email-using-apps-script-based-on-data-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 1):

Data from a spreadsheet can be inserted into a Gmail draft email (which can contain HTML) by using the [Yet Another Mail Merge](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/mail-merge) add-on in Google Sheets.